# Change PKStroke position in PencilKit

Tags: swift, pencilkit

I currently try to implement my own lasso tool in Swift in order to change the position of my Strokes drawn on a Pencil Kit Canvas. I select strokes by storing the indices of the strokes that are inside my drawn Rect.

```
func select(rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 5)
        for i in 0..<canvas.drawing.strokes.count {

            for point in canvas.drawing.strokes[i].path {
                if path.contains(point.location) {
                    selected.append(i)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a DragGesture on this Rect and send the translation to my moveSelected() function.

```
func moveSelected(val: CGSize) {

        for i in selected {
            canvas.drawing.strokes[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: val.width, y: val.height)
        }

    }
```

In principle this works very well, but as soon as I select more than two lines the behavior becomes very laggy. The canvasViewDrawingDidChange() gets called every time the  moveSelected() function gets called from the .onChange of the DragGesture.
Is there a better way to change the position of the strokes to stop the laggy behavior?